# Generate nested json format like nvd3 StackAreaChart data

Tags: javascript, php, json, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm trying to produce a nested `json` like `nvd3 StackedAreaChart` uses:

```
    [
        {
            "key" : "North America" ,
            "values" : [ [ 1025409600000 , 23.041422681023] , [ 1028088000000 , 19.854291255832] ]

        },

        {
            "key" : "Africa" ,
            "values" : [ [ 1025409600000 , 7.9356392949025] , [ 1028088000000 , 7.4514668527298] ]

        },

    ]
```

source: http://plnkr.co/edit/CIGW0o?p=preview

I want to use data from my database.

How could I achieve that kind `json`? I'm not so familiar with nested `json` plus one thing I noticed in the structure of their `json` is that the values in the `values` object is a plain integers. It's not quoted like `"1025409600000"`. And when I'm trying to qoute it, the chart can't properly read the data.

**Questions**

1. How to produce nested `json` like `nvd3` uses? I've come to some research but nothing happens. I found something like I guess it will, but can't get it working. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501883/generate-nested-json-from-sql-using-php) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155231/create-nested-json-object-using-php-mysql) too.
2. Is it possible to `unquote` the value from nested `json` structure? If it is, how?

Here's what I'm currently working on:

```
        <?php

        require_once('conn.php');

        $sql = "SELECT ua.user_id,(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt.transac_date)*1000) AS transac_date,
                        CONCAT(ui.fname,' ',ui.lname) AS fullname,
                        SUM((dt.item_price - dt.item_srp) * dt.sold) as profit,
                        SUM((dt.item_price) * dt.sold) as total_sales
                FROM dsp_transactions dt
                INNER JOIN user_acct ua ON dt.user_id=ua.user_id
                INNER JOIN user_info ui ON ua.ui_id=ui.ui_id
                GROUP BY ua.user_id";
        $qry = $con->query($sql);

        $data = array();
        if($qry->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $qry->fetch_object()) {
                $data[] = array(

                    'key' => $row->fullname,
                    'values' => $row->user_id

                    );
            }
        } else {
            $data[] = null;
        }

        $con->close();

        echo json_encode($data);

        ?>
```

Which give me this value:

```
[{"key":"Juan Dela Cruz","values":["1461772800000","5665.00"]},{"key":"Maria Gonzales","values":["1461772800000","275.00"]},{"key":"Apolinario Mabini","values":["1461772800000","100.00"]}]
```

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

For further information I want something like this to happen:

```
         dsp      |    sales     |   profit    |     date    
    --------------+--------------+-------------+--------------
        Juan      |    500       |     100     |    04/24/2016
    --------------+--------------+-------------+--------------
        Maria     |    600       |     200     |    04/24/2016
    --------------+--------------+-------------+--------------
       Apolinario |    700       |     300     |    04/24/2016
    --------------+--------------+-------------+--------------
        Juan      |    550       |     150     |    04/25/2016
```

Will return like this in `json` format

```
    [
        {
            "key" : "Juan",
            "values" : [ ["04/24/2016", "500"], ["04/25/2016", "550"] ]  // "values" loop twice because "juan" has two sales

        },
        {
            "key" : "Maria",
            "values" : [ ["04/24/2016", "600"] ]

        },
        {
            "key" : "Apolinario",
            "values" : [ ["04/24/2016", "700"] ]

        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The user id's coming back will be converted to strings. You can convert them back to floats using php:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.doubleval.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Comment: `doubleval()` function works! Thanks. But how about the nested json?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem starts with how you handled the data returned by your query. As I understand the problem, you want to group all the transaction date and sales (or profit) per person. Thus you need to manipulate the array before encoding it.

See if this snippet runs, do tell me if an error fires, but basically, this is the logic I see that solves the problem:

```
<?php

require_once('conn.php');

$sql = "SELECT ua.user_id,(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt.transac_date)*1000) AS transac_date,
                CONCAT(ui.fname,' ',ui.lname) AS fullname,
                SUM((dt.item_price - dt.item_srp) * dt.sold) as profit,
                SUM((dt.item_price) * dt.sold) as total_sales
        FROM dsp_transactions dt
        INNER JOIN user_acct ua ON dt.user_id=ua.user_id
        INNER JOIN user_info ui ON ua.ui_id=ui.ui_id
        GROUP BY transac_date, ua.user_id";
$qry = $con->query($sql);

$data = array();
$individual_row = array();
if($qry->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = pg_fetch_object($qry)) {
        //we find if there is an existing row with the person
        $indexOfIndividualRow = array_search($row->dsp, array_column($data, 'key'));
        //if no rows of the person are added yet
        if(empty($indexOfIndividualRow)&& !is_numeric($indexOfIndividualRow))
        {
            $individual_row['key'] = $row->dsp;
            $individual_row['values'] = array(array($row->date, $row->sales));
            array_push($data, $individual_row);
        }
        //if there is a row with person as key
        else 
        {
            //if there is a 'values' key
            if(isset($data[$indexOfIndividualRow]['values'])){
                array_push($data[$indexOfIndividualRow]['values'], array($row->date, $row->sales));
            }
            //else if there is no 'values' key
            else $data[$indexOfIndividualRow]['values'] = array($row->date, $row->sales);
        }
    }
}
else {
    $data[] = null;
}

$con->close();

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Did you try my code? I think that's what my solution aims to output.

Comment: Yeah. I just tried. But returning me only the first loop in `values`. I think it's because my `query` only get the `user's id` and I used `GROUP BY`. It's not getting the two dates for "juan". Any idea how to fix my `query` with your code? I already tried anything just to meet the output with your codes but can't get it working.

Comment: You should try changing the `GROUP BY ua.user_id` clause in your query to `GROUP BY transac_date, ua.user_id`. By that you can get the sales per date, not by person only. See edit above. Try running it.

Comment: Its just loop the data twice in the first object.
[{"key":"Juan Dela Cruz","values":["1461772800000","5115.00"]},{"key":"Maria Gonzales","values":["1461772800000","275.00"]},{"key":"Apolinario Mabini","values":["1461772800000","100.00"]},{"key":"Juan Dela Cruz","values":["1461859200000","550.00"]}]

Comment: Hi! I solved it.. :) Changed if condition and the 'values' key initialization. Please refer to the edit.